# How can I disable only one button of a kendo-grid-command-column? Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Supose that I have a kendo-grid with 10 rows, I have a command-column on the grid (edit & remove)
How can I get disabled the remove-command button of the last row???

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="dataDesglose" [selectable]="true" [navigable]="true"
[reorderable]="true" [resizable]="true" [sortable]="true" style="height: 45vh"
(edit)="editDesglose($event)" (remove)="deleteDesglose($event)">
<kendo-grid-column field="Comisionista" title="Comisionista" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="Desde" title="Desde" width="100">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>{{ dataItem.Desde | currency:'MXN' }}
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="Hasta" title="Hasta" width="100">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>{{ dataItem.Hasta | currency:'MXN' }}
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="Porcentaje" title="Porcentaje" width="100">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>{{ dataItem.Porcentaje | currency:'%' }}
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-command-column title="Actions" width="190">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-i="i">
<button kendoGridEditCommand [primary]="true">Editar</button>
<button kendoGridRemoveCommand>Eliminar</button>
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-command-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disable attribute from html?

`<button kendoGridRemoveCommand disabled>Eliminar</button>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

Or if you prefer to disable it on the conditional:

`[disabled]="conditional"`

Comment: yes, but that disables the button on every row. I wanna disable only the button on last row